# How to count the number of different type of characters in file using C.

Tags: c, file

The characters may contain any numeric, alphabets, symbols such as :;@ etc.
one method is to use a switch case statement as show below. but thats going to be simple and long process. Is there any other method short method possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
int ch,count[36]= {0};
if (fp == NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr,
        "Failed to open input.txt: %s\n",
         strerror(errno));
}
else
{
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
    case 'a':
        count[0]++;
        break;
    case 'b':
        count[1]++;
        break;
    default:
        count[2]++;
    }
}

fclose(fp);
}
    printf("count a is %d", count[0]);
    printf("count b is %d", count[1]);
    printf("count c is %d", count[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make the arraay 256 big, then it's a simple `count[ch]++` and you can count ANY bytes in the file.

Answer (score 5):

In ASCII, printable characters have codes from  `0x20` to `0x7E`, so less than 128 characters. So for ASCII just use an array of 128 characters:

```
int count[128] = {0};
```

Update your count with:

```
count[ch]++;
```

and print printable characters with something like this:

```
for (i = 0x20; i <= 0x7E; i++)
{
    printf("count %c is %d", i, count[i]);
}
```

Comment: That's dangerous because [extended ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) can cause you to walk off the end of your array.  So better to make it 256 rather than 128.

Comment: @LaceCard: `if (ch <= 0x7E) count[ch]++;`

Comment: Presuming Ascii this would seem to work, but on a UTF8 file the counts would be off.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array of size 2^8 and increase the corresponding member.

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    characters[ ch ] += 1 ;
....
```

The index of the array `characters` fits the [asci table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: This works for 8bit Ascii, but what about UTF8? He did says types of characters not bytes.

Comment: I used a method similar to this when I made a toy C program to count the frequency of different byte values on a given block device. It was mainly an exercise in using Apple Objective C blocks with C but you might find https://gist.github.com/iwillspeak/4055319#file-bytes-c-L48 of interest.

Comment: @Sqeaky [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) can read UTF8? It returns a char promoted to int. You should use `fgetwc()` for a wide char.

Comment: UTF8 is variable width(as few a 1 byte as many as 4 bytes represent a sinlge character), there is no direct formula correlating how many char/bytes and how many characters. Despite this, your code seems like in practice it would work.

Answer (score 1):

if you are reading ASCII characters:

> frequency[ch]++;

where frequency is integer array of size 128

Answer (score 1):

If you use the functions from `<ctype.h>` (`isalpha`, `isdigit`, `ispunct`, etc) in a series of `if` statements inside your `while` loop, you could categorize them fairly easily.

PS: for a list of these functions, see:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/